# Retrieving most recent data in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Total disclosure: I'm a SQL beginner.

I have a data set of certain accounting and governance metrics for US companies. It has about 15 columns and roughly 18 million rows. Each row is a unique combination of company, date and metric being measured. The columns include certain identifiers like isin number, ticker symbol, etc, the date the metric was released, the metric description, and the metric itself.

What I'm trying to do is write a query that will yield the NEWEST values for a certain metric for all companies. In my hopeless search over the past few days I've come to think that the GROUP BY clause may be what I'm looking for. However, it doesn't seem to do exactly what I need. I've got it working with just 2 columns: isin number (company identifier), and date. In other words, I can spit out a list that shows the most recent date for each company, but I'm not sure how to add more columns to this, how to specify what metric to look at.

Any guidance would be appreciated, even if it's just pointing me in the right direction towards what kind of commands I should be looking into.

Thanks!

EDIT: Wow. Thanks for the quick and thorough replies. And point taken on the clarity and example data sets/starting query. Update: I think I have it working. Here's what I used:

```
SELECT a1.["id_isin_number"], a1.["metric_description"], a1.["date_period_ends"], a1.["company_metric_value"], a2.maxdate
FROM [AGR Metrics].[dbo].[Audit_Integrity_Metric_Data_File_NA Original_0] a1

INNER JOIN (
           SELECT a2.["id_isin_number"], MAX(a2.["date_period_ends"]) AS maxdate

           FROM [AGR Metrics].[dbo].[Audit_Integrity_Metric_Data_File_NA Original_0] a2

           GROUP BY a2.["id_isin_number"]
           ) a2

ON a1.["date_period_ends"] = a2.maxdate
  AND a1.["id_isin_number"] = a2.["id_isin_number"]
  WHERE a1.["metric_description"] = '"Litigation: Class Action"'
```

I'm looking over the responses now to make sure I'm doing this as efficiently as possible.

Comment: Obligatory follow up question if you're a beginner: Do you know what "Database Normalization" is? If no, i suggest you to learn about it because it will save you a lot of pain in the future, If yes, is the database normalized?

Comment: For future reference: It's easy to assume what your current query is, but you should include it in your question, and sample data goes a long way too.  People like to see the code you've tried, even if you've got a solid description of it.

Comment: Group by is as name suggest used for just grouping on certain basis , Like you can group by rows or entries based upon different criterias say company , But this can not fetch you latest data however, try using `orderBy` clause if you have date field than you can use `orderBy` on date column and select Top(1) entry of it .

Comment: @STTLCU it's not `Normalization` always helps.

Comment: @SurajSingh what? i don't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `ROW_NUMBER()` function for this (if using SQL Server 2005 or newer):

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY isin ORDER BY [date] DESC) AS RowRank
      FROM YourTable
     )sub
WHERE RowRank = 1
```

Just list out the fields you want in place of * if you don't want them all returned.

The `ROW_NUMBER()` function adds a number to each row, `PARTITION BY` is optional and is used to define a group for which numbering will start over at 1, in this case, you want the most recent for each value of `isin` so we `PARTITION BY` that.  `ORDER BY` is required and defines the order of the numbering, in this case by date.

Your current query can also be used, but the `ROW_NUMBER()` method is simpler and more efficient:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM YourTable a
JOIN (SELECT isin, MAX([date])
      FROM YourTable
      GROUP BY isin
     )b
 ON a.isin = b.isin
 AND a.[date] = b.[date]
```

Answer (score 0):

Well as you quote the `date the metric was released` , So you can use it to sort your table using Order By .
This is a very basic example which can be used to simply sort data and selecting top 1 value.

Please refer [This](http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql-commands.htm)

```
 CREATE  TABLE trialOne (
      Id INT NULL,  
      NAME VARCHAR(50) NULL,
      [Date] DATETIME NULL

    )
SELECT * FROM dbo.ETProgram
INSERT INTO trialone VALUES(1,'john','2009-01-06 11:39:51.827') 
INSERT INTO trialone VALUES(2,'joseph','2010-01-06' ) 
INSERT INTO trialone VALUES(3,'Ajay','2009-05-06' ) 
INSERT INTO trialone VALUES(4,'Dave','2009-11-06' ) 
INSERT INTO trialone VALUES(5,'jonny','2004-01-06') 
INSERT INTO trialone VALUES(6,'sunny','2005-01-06') 
INSERT INTO trialone VALUES(7,'elle','2013-01-06' ) 
INSERT INTO trialone VALUES(8,'mac','2012-01-06' ) 
INSERT INTO trialone VALUES(8,'Sam','2008-01-06' ) 
INSERT INTO trialone VALUES(10,'xxxxx','2013-08-06')

SELECT TOP(1)name FROM trialone ORDER BY Date DESC
```